# Angular 2 push messages to global component

Tags: angular

New to Angular 2. I'm working on global error component which will show error 
messages from all views/components.

How can I communicate global error component from another component.**

```
//  appComponent.ts
appComponet will have several components
    @Component({
        selector: 'app',
        template: `
            <notification-component></notification-component>
            <header-component></header-component>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            <footer-component></footer-component>
    })
    **I like to push messages to notification-component.
    here is the notificationComponent**
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
      selector: 'notification-component',
      templateUrl:"app/notification/notification-view.component.html",
      styleUrls:["app/notification/css/notification-view.component.css"]
    })
    NotificationViewComponent will have notificationMessages
    export class NotificationViewComponent implements OnInit {
         notificationMessages = [];
         hideNotification: boolean = false;
        ngOnInit(): void {
            this.notificationMessages.push("We arre sorry -- an error occurred while one of your request. ");
        }    
         hideNotificationSection () {
            this.hideNotification = true;
         }
    }
```

I am trying to push messages from another component (not from app Component).

How can I push the messages to notification component from another component?

Comment: Please format your code and ask a specific question that can be directly addressed.

Comment: i am new to this forum. i will try to improve

Answer (score 0):

Report your errors to a Service shared to all the components you have. Use the rxjs/Subject class to 'emit' the error to any component subscribed to it.

You will need 2 imports.

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'; // to emit errors
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription'; // to subscribe to the emiter
```

Here is and example of an error service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorService {

    public subject_error: Subject<string> = new Subject();

    public addError(error: string){
        subject_error.next('error');
    }
}
```

Subscribe to the subject wherever you want (do not forget to cancel subscription):

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class MyComponent OnInit, OnDestroy {

    private subscription:Subscription = new Subscription();

    constructor(
        private errorService: ErrorService,
    ) {}
    ngOnInit(){
        this.subscription = this.errorService.subject_error.subscribe(
            error => console.log(error)
        );
    }
    ngOnDestroy(){
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Adding an error is as simple as this :

```
this.errorService.addError('an error occurred');
```